# Intercept NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected() to make backstack pop with "inclusive = true"

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-navigationview

I have connected my menu xml and the Android Navigation Components via `navigation_view.setupWithNavController(navController)` and everything is working perfectly. Part of my menu is the Logout option. If the user selects this navigation destination, the app should navigate to the `AuthorizationFragment` **and pop the backstack to this Fragment with inclusive set to true** to remove all previous fragments.

I looked into the code of the navigation library and reached the point where this should happen:

*NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected():*

```
/**
 * Attempt to navigate to the {@link NavDestination} associated with the given MenuItem. This
 * MenuItem should have been added via one of the helper methods in this class.
 *
 * <p>Importantly, it assumes the {@link MenuItem#getItemId() menu item id} matches a valid
 * {@link NavDestination#getAction(int) action id} or
 * {@link NavDestination#getId() destination id} to be navigated to.</p>
 * <p>
 * By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination.
 * Menu items that have <code>android:menuCategory="secondary"</code> will not pop the back
 * stack.
 *
 * @param item The selected MenuItem.
 * @param navController The NavController that hosts the destination.
 * @return True if the {@link NavController} was able to navigate to the destination
 * associated with the given MenuItem.
 */
public static boolean onNavDestinationSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item,
        @NonNull NavController navController) {
    NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
    if ((item.getOrder() & Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY) == 0) {
        builder.setPopUpTo(findStartDestination(navController.getGraph()).getId(), false);
    }
    NavOptions options = builder.build();
    try {
        //TODO provide proper API instead of using Exceptions as Control-Flow.
        navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is, whether there is a way to override this method and to build NavOptions that are popping the backstack to the destination id with the inclusive option set to true?

Comment: Adding `app:popUpTo= @+id/authorization_fragment` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`  to your action didn't work out for you ?

Comment: That's the problem. The action is not built by me in this case. Instead the code I posted is executed by the navigation components. It is generating the navigation options if your NavigationDrawer was set up using `navigation_view.setupWithNavController(navController)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As usual, sleeping over a problem helps. I found out that you can easily set your own `NavigationItemSelectedListener`. Also the method I am mentioning in my question is public static, so it can also easily be called as fallback functionality.

Here's my code:

```
navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->

    // check for my special case where I want to pop everything
    // from the backstack until we reach the login fragment
    if (item.itemId == R.id.fragment_auth) {
        val options = NavOptions.Builder()
            .setPopUpTo(navController.currentDestination!!.id, true)
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .build()
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_authFragment, null, options)
        true // return true -> we handled this navigation event

    } else {

        // Fallback for all other (normal) cases.
        val handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)

        // This is usually done by the default ItemSelectedListener.
        // But there can only be one! Unfortunately.
        if (handled) drawer_layout.closeDrawer(navigation_view)

        // return the result of NavigationUI call
        handled
    }
}
```